# How can I fix my div overlay for Firefox?

Tags: jquery, css

I have [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TzQ95/1/) where I put a "cursor" div on top of a table. A function moves the cursor around by manipulating the CSS attributes `left`, `top`, `width` and `height`.

In Chrome 24 and MSIE 9.0, the cursor completely covers the red border of a cell and it extends one pixel outside of the cell (so the cursor draws over the cell's border and leaks into all neighboring cells, it doesn't leak *into* the cell).

In Firefox 19.0, the cursor is shifted one pixel down/left.

How can I fix the code for most browsers?

Comment: Have you tried to use `innerWidth()` and `innerHeight()` for `var width; var height`?

Comment: The left/top values are wrong, not the size (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
 #cursor {
     margin-left:-1px !important;
     margin-top:-1px !important;
  }
}
```

tested in ur [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TzQ95/5/)

to fix in Opera (if u need) user a hack like this:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000), not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
#cursor {
    property:value;
}
}
```

Hope that help